# Drupal 7 - Get pages created from custom modules listed under Entity reference field

Tags: 7, entities, database

I'm using Drupal 7 Entity Reference field in one of the content types. I want to populate the Auto complete field with pages created using my custom module.

Currently in the options, it is showing only the content types that are existing. How can I achieve this?

Comment: make a unique content-type for these pages

Comment: Actually, these pages are different. These are listed in `hook_menu()` in my module.

Comment: then you need to convert them to entities, or create a custom field that in your module that allows this reference

Comment: Any tutorial for converting nodes into entities?

Comment: you have to define entities yourself, and also write the conversion ... for entities, the entity API(https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) can be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you serve regular nodes of a new content-type in your hook_menu callback ? so you could easily reference them !

```
$html = node_view(node_load(948));
```